# Need to take backup from other server on network using AutoMySQLBackup

Tags: mysql

We have two servers namely serverA and serverB. I need to take mysql database backup of serverA staying at serverB. The tool I need to use is "AutoMySQLBackup".

I got the link for downloading it:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/automysqlbackup/

Extracted the tar and changed the config file in `/etc/automysqlbackup/automysqlbackup.conf` as per my need.

As I run `automysqlbackup`, I get the backups on daily basis though there are warnings:

```
###### WARNING ######
Errors reported during AutoMySQLBackup execution.. Backup failed
Error log below..
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqlshow: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysqldump: Got error: 1142: SELECT, LOCK TABLES command denied to user 'root'@'localhost' for table 'accounts' when using LOCK TABLES
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
```

But, I need to take the backup of remote server and don't find the way to do that using this tool. I tried using :

```
ssh serverA@ip-address | automysqlbackup
```

but nothing is happening.

Note: I can't reply to answers so i am mentioning it here. I need to get the backup directly from serverA to serverB with the help of automysqlbackup like the way mysqldump or someother tool does.

mysqldump --host 192.168.1.15 -P 3306 -u dev -pmjQ9Y mydb > mydb.sql

Is there way to pipe automysqldump with ssh?
No scp,rsync.
I have access to certain database in serverA while accessing from serverB.

If anyone of you have used this tool, then please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Are you able to do the backup? as i see an error on that message i got confused about it.

2: Did you set up a CRON to run the script daily? First thing that come to mind was to run a ssh copy of the backup to server B in the CRONjob (using SCP command)

Comment: hi luisbessa, yes i can get the backup of all the databases on /var/backup/db/daily directory. I haven't set cron for the script. All i did was running automysqlbackup and it takes the backup. But as i said, i would want the backup of remote server in my local machine. How can i use scp with cron for that ?

Comment: Take it from here how to SCP: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304895/how-to-scp-a-folder-from-remote-to-local 

If you want, put it in a cron job and you will make a copy every day/week/month as you wish

Comment: is there way to use automysqlbackup along with ssh without scp or rsync?

Comment: along with ssh i believe not by default, if you setup automysqlbackup on ServerB with a host as ServerA it will allow you but you need to give access to user from other IP (ServerB)

Comment: where should i give the access? could you provide any idea regarding the commands?

Comment: dude you should try to google it first no? not that hard.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348506/grant-remote-access-of-mysql-database-from-any-ip-address

Comment: Thank you for the help. Tried that , but could not find the solution without scp/rsync.

Comment: you manage to do it? although i believe its not the best solution since you are opening your bd to the outside.. i would advance for the solution with scp ;)